# Event based integration between Azure and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, azure-blob-storage

As of today, we have an AWS based solution - whenever a new object is added to S3 bucket it publishes an event to SQS which triggers Lambda function to execute some business logic. **S3 -> Event -> SQS -> Lambda**

Now we want to cater to Azure Storage along with AWS S3 - On Azure Blob storage, when a Blob file is added to the storage container, we would want the existing AWS Lambda function to be triggered.

To start with, I could think of two options with a push based near-real time manner
**Option# 1: Azure Blob -> Event -> ???? -> AWS SQS -> AWS Lambda**
Are there integration services available to integrate Azure EventBus / EventGrid to AWS SQS/AWS EventBridge directly? If not what are the alternatives to Push event into SQS

**Option# 2:  Azure   Blob -> Event ->  Azure Event Bus?? -> ???? -> AWS Lambda**
What are the possible options from Azure to trigger AWS Lambda directly
and what could be downside if we choose this path instead of option# 1

Would highly appreciate suggestions and thoughts.

Comment: You could either use AWS Lambda native https endpoint or you could use an AWS API Gateways in front of the lambda

Answer (score 0):

Amazon API Gateway will natively integrate with SQS. So on the AWS side, I would have:

API GW -> AWS SQS -> AWS Lambda

I don't know Azure as well, so it would depend on whether Azure Event Bus could meet the requirements of sending to a HTTP endpoint with the specific security requirements. If not I think you would be best with some form of serverless compute on the Azure side to send to API Gateway.